# connect to DB from nb: could not translate host name to address error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, psycopg2

I'm having trouble connecting to a DB from a jupyter nb on a mac.
psycopg2 complains about an `OperationalError`. My code:

```
import sqlalchemy as db

# build connection string
connection_string = f"postgresql://{db_cred['username']}:{db_cred['password']}@{db_cred['host']}/{db_cred['database']}"

# create engine
engine = db.create_engine(connection_string)

# connect
conn = engine.connect()
```

returns

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "db.production.info" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Needless to say, the DB credentials are correct. The [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#error-e3q8) on these errors isn't very helpful, and [most](https://github.com/instructure/lti_tool_provider_example/issues/4) [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750715/could-not-translate-host-name-db-to-address-using-postgres-docker-compose-and) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751202/psycopg2-operationalerror-could-not-translate-host-name-to-address-using-psycop) revolve around Docker, which I'm not using in this case.

The only exception was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055882/psql-could-not-translate-host-name-somepostgres-to-address-name-or-service-n) thread, which proposes using the IP address instead of the host name. I did that, and get the following different error:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "192.XXX.XX.XX", port XXXX failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The original error sounds like a DNS issue; the second error suggests that either there isn't a server running on that host, or the Postgresql port is firewalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be that an SSH tunnel was necessary.

From a shell script, execute the command:

```
ssh -L 9999:db.production.info:[port number] -N [username]@192.XXX.XX.XX
```

this will tunnel `db.production.info:[port number]` to your `localhost` on port `9999`.

You can then adapt the connection string as

```
'postgresql://username:password@localhost:9999/[the DB name]'
```